# Equivalent of $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2x+1})$ in zero

Tags: asymptotics

My task is to find the equivalent of $$\tan\left (\frac{\pi}{2x+1}\right )$$ in zero.
I tried using the formula $\tan(x)\sim x$ in zero, and got $\frac{\pi}{2x+1}$ and then this is $\sim\pi$ in zero. But according to the teacher the right answer is $-2\pi x$

Can you please point me to the right direction?

Comment: This is not clear. What do you mean by "in zero"?

Comment: @Klangen I'm not sure what's called in english. According to the definition $f\sim_a g\Leftrightarrow\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$, i'm asking here when a = 0.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to find a linear approximation *around* zero.

Comment: If your task is to find a function $g$ such that $\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ then there would be many choices for $g$; I suppose there is a further constraint, namely, $g$ should be of the form $g(x)=mx+b$? Even then the answer is unique only if $f(a)=0.$ But a "linear approximation" would be unique if $f$ is differentiable at $a.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $f(x) = \tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2x+1} \right)$, and $f'(x) = -\frac{2 \pi \sec^2 \pi/(2x+1)}{(x+1)^2}$.

Then to find the first-order approximation, we need to find:

$$f(0) + f'(x) (x-0)$$
$$= 0 + -2\pi x$$

Comment: Thanks! It's the first time i hear about linear approximation.

Comment: This comes from the general form for a Taylor series around zero: $f(0) + f'(x)(x-0) + \frac{1}{2!}f''(x) \cdot (x-0)^2 + \frac{1}{3!} f^{(3)} (x) \cdot (x-0)^3 + \cdots$. and making an approximation by discarding the higher-order terms.